# Integration of pre-trained word vectors in topic modeling in R

Tags: r, lda, topic-modeling

I am relatively new to the domain of topic modeling so I hope this isn't a stupid question.

I have a text corpus of 7k documents which are mostly relatively short (just a few words). As standard LDA produces only moderately good results, I want to include word vectors that are pre-trained on a large external corpus (like these: https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/). 
However, I haven't found anything that explains understandably how I should proceed (I found some information about the implementation in Python, but I need a solution for R). 
After downloading the pre-trained word vectors, how do I integrate them in the LDA modeling process for my own corpus?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The package `text2vec` has an implementation of `GloVe`.

- Package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/index.html
- Vignette on GloVe: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/text2vec/vignettes/glove.html